# How to dynamically add new Labels below eachother in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a leaderboard in my Javafx application. To achieve this, I want to dynamically add Labels containing the name of the player below eachother. I first used a gridpane like this:

```
Gridpane pane
for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
{
     Label l = new Label();
     l.setText(users.get(i).getName());
     pane.add(l, 2, 1);
}
```

(I can't show the whole code, because it is a school project and I'm not allowed to).

But, when I do this, all the names will appear on exactly the same position. Then, I tried to manually change their y locations, but apparently, this changes nothing.

So, what is another good way to dynamically place elements below eachother?

Comment: Have you tried using a VBox

Comment: Also, you CAN read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: Change the `rowIndex`: `pane.add(l, 2, 1+i);`???

Comment: @fabian is right, that would solve your issue. You may want to look into using something else though, like a ListView, or a VBox, like Austin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

**From API docs of GridPane...**

Applications may also use convenience methods which combine the steps of setting the constraints and adding the children:

```
 GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
 gridpane.add(new Button(), 1, 0); // column=1 row=0
 gridpane.add(new Label(), 2, 0);  // column=2 row=0
```

Try to understand what would be arguments for your example... (hint - if you are adding all labels to column 2, row 1 what happens?